# Query in asp.net core

Tags: mysql, linq, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a query table like this, people let me ask how can I get the Positions data of the current user when I get the userid to query with the Document table.

```
var claimsIdentity = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;
        var userId = claimsIdentity.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier)?.Value.ToString();
        var query = from c in _context.Documents
                    join u in _context.Users on c.UserID equals u.Id
                    join p in _context.Positions on u.Id equals p.UserID
                    where c.UserID.ToString() == userId
                    select new { c, u, p };
```

Comment: if the purpose is just to get `Positions` data of the current User and there is no filter related to `Documents`, there should be just 2 tables involved here: `User` & `Position`. So you don't need to join the `Documents` in this query, which may produce duplicate info of `Position` and make it harder to extract the final set of `Positions`. Removing the `_context.Documents`, you have the final query returning all `Positions` each of which is paired with the corresponding `User`. That's should be the data you want.

Comment: I want to query 2 table Document and Position through User Current

Comment: I've just added an answer to help you with that. I hope that's what you want. If not, just leave your comment to make it clearer. Again, with this kind of question, the chance for you to have an answer is ***much higher*** than other kinds of question. Because it's just query-related and many users love LINQ. But you should be more clear on the requirement, ***especially*** the format of data you want to have.

Answer (score 1):

The data you query is almost enough, but it contains duplicate entries of `Document` and `Position`. If you want the final query to be put in a single object like this:

```
{
    User = ...,
    Documents = ...,
    Positions = ...
}
```

You just need to project it using Linq-to-object (because all the data is loaded and ready for projection on the client):

```
var result = (from document in _context.Documents
             join user in _context.Users on document.UserID equals user.Id
             join position in _context.Positions on user.Id equals position.UserID
             where document.UserID.ToString() == userId
             select new { document, user, position }).AsEnumerable()
             .GroupBy(e => e.user.Id)
             .Select(g => new {
                 User = g.First().user,
                 Documents = g.GroupBy(e => e.document.Id)
                              .Select(e => e.First().document),
                 Positions = g.GroupBy(e => e.position.Id)
                              .Select(e => e.First().position)
             }).FirstOrDefault();
```

If you don't want to fetch the user info, you don't need to join that DbSet but instead join the two `Document` and `Position` directly like this:

```
var result = (from document in _context.Documents
              join position in _context.Positions on document.UserID equals position.UserID
             where document.UserID.ToString() == userId
             select new { document, position }).AsEnumerable()
             .GroupBy(e => e.document.UserID)
             .Select(g => new {
                 Documents = g.GroupBy(e => e.document.Id)
                              .Select(e => e.First().document),
                 Positions = g.GroupBy(e => e.position.Id)
                              .Select(e => e.First().position)
             }).FirstOrDefault();
```

Note that I suppose your `Document` and `Position` both have its own primary key property of `Id` (adjust that to your actual design).
Finally, usually if your `User` entity type exposes ***navigation collection properties*** to the `Document` and `Position`. We can have a better (but equal) query like this:

```
var user = _context.Users
                   .Include(e => e.Documents)
                   .Include(e => e.Positions)
                   .FirstOrDefault(e => e.Id.ToString() == userId);
```

It's much simpler because all the joining internally translated by the EFCore. The magic is embedded right into the design of ***navigation collection properties***.

I would like to talk about the important note of the condition `UserID.ToString() == userId` or `Id.ToString() == userId`. You should avoid that because it would be translated into a query that breaks the using of index for filtering. Instead try parsing for an `int` userId first (looks like it's a string in your case) and use that parsed `int` directly for comparison in the query, like this:

```
if(!int.TryParse(userId, out var intUserId)){
    //return or throw exception
}
                           
//here we have an user id of int, use it directly in your query
var user = _context.Users
                   .Include(e => e.Documents)
                   .Include(e => e.Positions)
                   .FirstOrDefault(e => e.Id == intUserId);
```

That applies similarly to other queries as well.